# Cross-level influence in multilevel model for longitudinal data with time-invariant outcome

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, latent-variable, mplus

I don't have a lot of experience with multilevel models and Mplus, so I'm unsure if my approach is appropriate.

I would therefore be very grateful for any help and feedback!

I have data from an experiment.
3 groups of participants each went through 4 trials in which they watched instructional videos. After each trial, their state motivation was measured using 4 items. At the end of the experiment, all videos were rated together using one scale and their trait motivation (4 items) was measured as a control variable.
I would now like to examine the relationship between the video ratings and the state-motivation ratings. At the same time, I would like to control for group membership and trait motivation.

To do this, I have specified a multilevel model in which the ratings after each trial (level 1) are nested within the individual subjects (level 2). In particular, I am interested in the cross-level influence of video rating (level 2) on state motivation (level 1).

At level 1 I have a latent dependent variable (state-motivation) with 4 indicators. Additionally, I want to control for the video number.
On level 2 I have the video rating as an independent variable and group membership and trait motivation as covariates.

The data is in long format.

Here is the corresponding Mplus syntax:

```
USEVARIABLE = ID !individual
NIS !videorating
StMoIt1-StMoIt4 !Item 1-4 of the state motivation 
TrMoIN1-TrMoIN4 !Item 1-4 of the trait motivation
video !number of the video
high mid; ! group membership as dummy coding
CLUSTER = ID;
WITHIN = video;
BETWEEN = TrMoIN1 TrMoIN2 TrMoIN3 TrMoIN4 NIS high mid;
MISSING=;
DEFINE:
  high = 0;
  IF (group == 3) then high = 1;
  low = 0;
  IF (group == 1) then low = 1;
  mid = 0;
  IF (group == 2) then mid = 1;
ANALYSIS: TYPE= TWOLEVEL;

MODEL:

%WITHIN%
StMot BY StMoIt1-StMoIt4*(p1-p4);
StMot ON video;

%BETWEEN%
StMotB BY StMoIt1-StMoIt4*(p1-p4);
TrMot BY TrMoIN1-TrMoIN4;
NIS ON high mid;
StMotB ON NIS TrMot;
```

Is this multilevel model an appropriate approach to answer my question?
If not, could you point me in the right direction?
I have also thought about a growth model, however I am not interested in changes over time/videos and the state motivation is very stable across videos.
I am also particularly unsure about using long-format data in this.

Thank you very much!